# Is it just me or has Mutter stopped unredirecting full screen program displays?

Tags: 19.10, compositing, mutter

In 19.04, in X sessions, fullscreen displays such as Youtube videos were unredirected from Mutter compositing. That was obvious while using the intel modesetting driver, from the tearing.

However, now that I switched to 19.10, I notice no more tearing on fs Youtube videos. In an older window manager such as Metacity however, tearing is still atrocious so I know the change isn't coming from the driver.

So is it just me or did Mutter stop systematically unredirecting full screen program displays ? And then, did they go back to unconditional compositing or are special criteria used to avoid compositing games' displays ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have problems with windows not being unredirected with 19.10 as well. Probably due to this bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1788

Updated:

I looks like this problem is fixed in Ubuntu Proposed (you can enable this extra repository in Software Sources under "Developer Options"). I upgraded mutter / libmutter-5-0 as well as gnome-shell (though only the mutter upgrades was probably necessary).

mutter/libmutter-5-0: 3.34.1+git20191107-1ubuntu1~19.10.1
gnome-shell: 3.34.1+git20191024-1ubuntu1~19.10.1

Fixed unredirecting for me!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I will probably wait for the next official update though, since I usually don't use Mutter when playing games anyway. I even had the habit of disabling full screen unredirection before this bug appeared (because I don't like tearing on my full screen Youtube videos), so one could say that this bug helps me in some sense. Maybe one day, when Mutter gives more control over unredirection, I will begin to use it even in a gaming environment !